# Best data structure when representing a simple electric circuit - C++

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, simulation

I'm doing a simple electric circuit system to simulate Ohm's law in C++. (V=I.R)

For this I'm using Qt to make the GUI. The user will be able to connect different pieces/components like Resistors, batteries, voltmeter, ammeter, light bulb and once a start button is clicked the voltmeters and ammeters should display readings. then the user should be able to add/remove batteries. While doing this user should realize that the R is a constant.

additionally if light bulbs were used they should light with some intensity according to the law.

I need to know how to represent in data structures in the code.

Comment: What did you try? You basically want to represent a non-oriented graph!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Unless the OP wants to simulate currents, in which it definitely will become a directed graph. :)

Comment: If we're into details, I'd say a weighted oriented graph not an oriented graph, since the current is a real number, not just "left / right". It may be equal to 0 as well!

Answer (score 7):

A circuit is a classic example for a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29) data structure, with your components being nodes and the connections edges.